# Is this Encryption and Decryption secure?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I have built windows app PasswordManager. I am encrypting and decrypting passwords using AESManaged. How secure is this? I tried to implement StringCipher.Encrypt(plainText, password) and StringCipher.Decrypt(encryptedText, password) but couldn't figure it out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

```
public class StringCipher 
    {
        public static string Encrypt(string input)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)));
        }
        public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input)
        {
            PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes("hjiweykaksd", new byte[] { 0x43, 0x87, 0x23, 0x72, 0x45, 0x56, 0x68, 0x14, 0x62, 0x84 });
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Aes aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.Key = pdb.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            aes.IV = pdb.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
            cs.Close();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
        public static string Decrypt(string input)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(input)));
        }
        public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] input)
        {
            PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes("hjiweykaksd", new byte[] { 0x43, 0x87, 0x23, 0x72, 0x45, 0x56, 0x68, 0x14, 0x62, 0x84 });
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Aes aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.Key = pdb.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            aes.IV = pdb.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
            cs.Close();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is AES, it is a famous encryption algorithm, but secure for what, how and where, are really opinion base

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani, I am passing hardcoded password "hjiweykaksd" to the PasswordDeriveBytes. If I pass the password through StringCipher(plaintext, password) I couldn't decrypt using StringCipher(encryptedtext, password) and StringCipher(encryptedtext, incorrectPassword) throws an exception. I am saving the encrypted password in the database and try to match the user input to decrypted password. But if the user inputs incorrect password it throws an exception which I do not know how to handle properly.

Comment: You have a long list to fix missing basic use of crypto (hardcoded password?? IV equals key, no integrity check,..). If user inputs an incorrect password, it indeed should throw an exception.

Comment: @gusto2 No, the IV doesn't match the key. It may just match it partly by accident because the `PasswordDeriveBytes` class is botched by Microsoft, who clearly state that you should not use it anymore.

Comment: I'm curious why are you encrypting passwords rather than using a salted hash?

Comment: @Flydog57 If you're using a salted hash instead of a (salted) PBKDF or specific password hash then you might not be performing best practice crypto yourself.